# ValueError when trying to write a for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, valueerror

When I run this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id': ['earn', 'earn','lose', 'earn'],
    'game': ['darts', 'balloons', 'balloons', 'darts']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
print(df.loc[[1],['id']] == 'earn')
```

The output is:
id      game
0  earn     darts
1  earn  balloons
2  lose  balloons
3  earn     darts
id
1  True

But when I try to run this loop:

```
for i in range(len(df)):  
     if (df.loc[[i],['id']] == 'earn'):  
         print('yes')  
     else:  
         print('no')
```

I get the error 'ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'
I am not sure what the problem is. Any help or advice is appreciated -- I am just starting.

I expected the output to be 'yes' from the loop. But I just got the 'ValueError' message. But, when I run the condition by itself, the output is 'True' so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: _But, when I run the condition by itself, the output is 'True'_ Show us that code.

Comment: Will len(df) return a number or is it df.size that's needed?  Is what caught my eyes first.

Comment: I haven't used dataframes at all, so maybe some subtlety is escaping me, but those two expressions look identical to me.  I don't understand why one would work but not the other.  Is `df` the same in both those examples?

Comment: Please post a working example - a small, simple dataframe, likely a few rows and an "id" column - the code and the output you get.

Comment: import pandas as pd

data = {'id': ['earn', 'earn','lose', 'earn'],
    'game': ['darts', 'balloons', 'balloons', 'darts']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)


print(df.loc[[1],['id']] == 'earn')

Comment: In that first example, is it `True` or is it a multiline print including "id" and `1 True`?.

Comment: Add that example into the question. Its too hard to read it in a comment. And BTW, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Okay I have updated the original question, sorry for not originally including. I think tdelaney you are correct, there is an "id" and a "1". Could you explain why that means my output is not really a boolean True?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its complicated. `pandas` is geared towards operating on entire groups of data, not individual cells. `df.loc` may create a new `DataFrame`, a `Series` or a single value, depending on how its indexed. And those produce `DataFrame`, `Series` or scalar results for the `==` comparison.

If the indexers are both lists, you get a new `DataFrame` and the compare is also a dataframe

```
>>> foo = df.loc[[1], ['id']]
>>> type(foo)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>>> foo
     id
1  earn
>>> foo == "earn"
     id
1  True
```

If one indexer is scalar, you get a new `Series`

```
>>> foo = df.loc[[1], 'id']
>>> type(foo)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> foo
1    earn
Name: id, dtype: object
>>> foo == 'earn'
1    True
Name: id, dtype: bool
```

If both indexers are scalar, you get a single cell's value

```
>>> foo = df.loc[1, 'id']
>>> type(foo)
<class 'str'>
>>> foo
'earn'
>>> foo == 'earn'
True
```

That last is the one you want. The first two produce containers where `True` is ambiguous (you need to decide if *any* or *all* values need to be `True`).

```
for i in range(len(df)):  
     if (df.loc[i,'id'] == 'earn'):  
         print('yes')  
     else:  
         print('no')
```

Or maybe not. Depending on what you intend to do next, create a series of boolean values for all of the rows at once

```
>>> earn = df[id'] == 'earn'
>>> earn
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: id, dtype: bool
```

now you can continue to make calculations on the dataframe as a whole.

Comment: THANK YOU! I had to re-read your comment 5 times before I understood it (because I am such a beginner, not because you wrote poorly) haha. But your explanation was super helpful thank you so much for writing all of that out!

Comment: @PrincessPeach `pandas` is that way. Its a heavy lift, but once you know the ins and outs, you can get a lot done.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if row.id == "earn":
        print("yes")
```